# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 - Hive update statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

When i trying to run the Hive update statement getting the following error.

```
    2021-02-25 15:38:54,934 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1592334694783_33388_r_000007_3: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":3}},"value":{"_col0":"T","_col1":1111111,"......."_col44":""}}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
```

The update query is simple.

All the columns in the Target table are string or Decimal .

Identified another issue point [Cloudera Link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/getting-error-while-submitting-merge-query/td-p/208991), But the problem is this query runs most of the time, but fails when run for certain type of Data.

Update Statement

```
UPDATE Table1 a
SET
email = MaskData(email,1)
WHERE  d_Date >= '2017-01-01' and
email IN (select distinct email from Table2);
```

Any Path forward or assistance will be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check can it be something wrong in data file `Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":3}},"value":{"_col0":"T","_col1":1111111,"......."_col44":""}}  `

Comment: It does not fail always. Some records are updated , some fail.Took the data in excel to analyze but not able to find any difference.

Comment: @leftjoin - I think i had identified the issue. When i had created a new table and tested it went fine. We insert the data into the managed and bucketed tables using spark. But Spark does not insert data into the bucketing table. Have raised a question in Stackoverflow for the same. Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424947/difference-between-spark-insert-and-hive-insert

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is not bucketed properly as we are inserting the data from Spark.
Had to re-do the complete tables and it was working properly.